# Insert works on different queries, but not the one for 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, insert

Your help is much appreciated! I get this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Thank you in advance

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
     K_NAME   varchar (30),
     V_NAME   INT,
     V_NAME2  INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT 
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM', 
        (SELECT Sum (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT),  MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT))       
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M),
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)
```

But this one below worked, I just needed to add this a second time, (the column for VAR2)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
    K_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    V_NAME INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT  
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM',  
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)
```

Comment: Try specifing the columns names on your insert: `INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5 (K_Name, V_Name, V_Name2)` and add a `GO` after the `DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5`

Comment: Why are you even checking whether that temporary table exists? It can only exist if it has been created by the current connection, so why is there any doubt it exists?

Comment: Thank you very much.. for reopening

Comment: Can't reproduce the error though: [fiddle](https://rextester.com/UYW82684). There must be something else going on.

Comment: It's a parsing issue, @HoneyBadger, due to the OP's odd design choice of having the same object have different definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a parsing error. You create the table `#VAR_TABLE5` in a prior batch, then in a latter batch, `DROP` and `CREATE` is again. When the second `INSERT` statement is parsed it is using the first definition of the table (with 3 columns) and hence the error. If you use the below, this reproduces the problem:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Elig_Smry_M (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT DECIMAL(8,2), NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT DECIMAL(8, 2), EOM_MBR_CNT DECIMAL(8,2), ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT DATE)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
     K_NAME   varchar (30),
     V_NAME   INT,
     V_NAME2  INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT 
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM', 
        (SELECT Sum (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT),  MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT))       
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M),
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
    K_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    V_NAME INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT  
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM',  
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)
```

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Don't run your statements in the same set of batches (i.e. different connections) and the error doesn't occur. Creating the same table in the same set of batches, with the different definitions seems like an design choice error anyway, so the simple fix it give the 2 objects different names:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Elig_Smry_M (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT DECIMAL(8,2), NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT DECIMAL(8, 2), EOM_MBR_CNT DECIMAL(8,2), ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT DATE)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
     K_NAME   varchar (30),
     V_NAME   INT,
     V_NAME2  INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT 
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM', 
        (SELECT Sum (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT),  MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT))       
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M),
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)

GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE6

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE6
(
    K_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    V_NAME INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE6
    SELECT  
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM',  
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)
GO
DROP TABLE #Elig_Smry_M;
```

If, for some bizarre reason, the objects "**must**" have the same name, then you will need to defer the parsing of the latter statement by using a "dynamic" statement to delay the validation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Elig_Smry_M (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT DECIMAL(8,2), NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT DECIMAL(8, 2), EOM_MBR_CNT DECIMAL(8,2), ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT DATE)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
     K_NAME   varchar (30),
     V_NAME   INT,
     V_NAME2  INT
)

INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT 
        'Average Plan Cost PMPM', 
        (SELECT Sum (CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT),  MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT))       
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M),
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)

GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#VAR_TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #VAR_TABLE5

CREATE TABLE #VAR_TABLE5
(
    K_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    V_NAME INT
)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO #VAR_TABLE5
    SELECT  
        ''Average Plan Cost PMPM'',  
        (SELECT SUM(CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT + NBNR_CLNT_NET_DUE_AMT ) / SUM(EOM_MBR_CNT) / DATEDIFF(M, MIN(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT), MAX(ELGBLTY_CLNDR_MNTH_END_DT)) 
         FROM #Elig_Smry_M)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
DROP TABLE #Elig_Smry_M;
```

Comment: I appreciate you all!... thank you so much,this is new to me... I was trying to see if it worked by piece mealing a query at  a time... I will change that....

Comment: You're welcome, @Frederica .If the above answers your question, please do consider marking it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful.

Comment: Ok, sure, I will try to figure out how to do that... i don't come here often